# QuickFIX/J : Set StartTime/EndTime so that the session runs perpetually

Tags: quickfixj

What values should the variables `StartTime` and `EndTime` be set to, so that the session runs perpetually.

I do not have a specific `EndTime`, and would like the session to keep running.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To have a session that will never reset you need to use the setting `NonStopSession=Y`

Actually the [config page](https://github.com/quickfix-j/quickfixj/blob/03c2d6ea38220f33126a8da2a9ad688aedf6a993/quickfixj-core/src/main/doc/usermanual/usage/configuration.html#L234) mentions that this is the same as setting `StartTime` and `EndTime` both to `00:00:00`. However, if I recall correctly the session will reset at `00:00:00` nevertheless (contrary to what the doc says).

Answer (score 0):

I haven't done this myself, but could you try with a combination of `Weekdays` and setting `StartTime` > `EndTime`?

From QuickFIX/J configuration on `Weekdays`:

> For daily sessions that are active on specific days of the week.
> Use in combination with StartTime and EndTime.
> Incompatible with StartDay and EndDay.
> If StartTime is before EndTime then the day corresponds to the StartTime.

It is also possible that just omitting `StartTime` and `EndTime` completely from your configuration does what you want. As I said, I never tried this before.